# Getting "Unexpected Token < " on my Google Maps api v3

Tags: mysql, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem, I'm using [this project](http://vikku.info/programming/google-maps-v3/draggable-directions/saving-draggable-directions-saving-waypoints-google-directions-google-maps-v3.htm) to use of base on my project. I tryied to get the same result of the guys project, and used the same project to test in my SQL.

I done the "index.php" works, and when I click "Save Route" it send a mensage "Updated", so, when I open "loady.htm" it give that error : "SintaxError: Unexpected Token < "

I used the same code, but changed the local host on process.php and the account and password.
But this is the unique change.

What's wrong on load.htm ? Or its an error on teste.php, I cant load the waypoints in "loady.htm"

Links for test:

[www.inventoresdegaragem.com/dbteste/index.htm](http://www.inventoresdegaragem.com/dbteste/index.htm) 
and 
www.inventoresdegaragem.com/dbteste/loady.htm

Edit 2: This is my process.php

```
<? ob_start(); header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');

@$data = $_REQUEST['*******'];


$host = 'localhost';
$usuario = '******';
$banco = '******';
$senha = '******';
$db = mysql_connect($host, $usuario, $senha);
mysql_select_db($banco, $db);



if($_REQUEST['command']=='save')
{

    $query = "update mapdir set value='$data'";
    if(mysql_query($query))die('bien');
    //die(mysql_error());
}

if($_REQUEST['command']=='fetch')
{
    $query = "select value from mapdir";
    if(!($res = mysql_query($query)));      
    $rs = mysql_fetch_array($res,1);
    die($rs['value']);      
}

?>
```

Comment: If the page that you gave us a link to works, but yours doesn't, it would be helpful if you provided a link to your page or posted the code of the page you have changed.  Your other option is to use a debugger and look at the line that it detects the error on.

Comment: www.inventoresdegaragem.com/dbteste/index.htm and www.inventoresdegaragem.com/dbteste/loady.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `process.php` cannot connect to your database.

> **Warning**:  mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Unknown MySQL server host 'http' (1) in **/home/i/inventoresdegara/www/dbteste/process.php** on line 10

It would appear that your current live version of `process.php` does not have `localhost` specified as the server. Note that it should be just a server name and should not include the protocol:

```
$host = 'localhost';
$host = 'www.mydomainnamehere.com';
```

(or whatever domain name you want to use) and **not**

```
$host = 'http://www.mydomainnamehere.com';
```

I believe the error is occurring because the database error message I've reproduced above is formatted as HTML and starts with `<`:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_connect() [<a href='function.mysql-connect'>function.mysql-connect</a>]: Unknown MySQL server host 'http' (1) in <b>/home/i/inventoresdegara/www/dbteste/process.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

The html on your "after" page is [not valid](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.inventoresdegaragem.com%2Fdbteste%2Floady.htm&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=00)

looks like jax.responseText is empty.

Comment: Thanks guy, but I dont have any idea that how to resolve it =/

Comment: I edited the question with my process.php, I think the error is on it